# Call utility function from a utility function in a Jenkins Pipeline Shared Library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am following the [example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/README.md) under *Accessing steps*. In `src/org/foo/Zot.groovy`  I would like to call a utility function defined in e.g. `src/org/foo/Bar.groovy`. How to do that?

I tried several things without success, e.g.:

```
// src/org/foo/Zot.groovy
package org.foo;

def bar = new org.foo.Bar()

def checkOutFrom(repo) {
  bar.someFunction()
  git url: "git@github.com:jenkinsci/${repo}"
}
```

In this case Jenkins hangs on loading the global library. I also tried to `import` the file.

Answer (score 1):

There have been reproduction of a similar, and probably related problem here:  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31484

I reproduced a similar situation using the Global CPS Library. The executor stack trace shows that the thread gets locked in InvokerInvocationException, like in the link provided.

I was able to workaround my small reproduce case by adding the @NonCPS annotation to all the called methods down the line.